# How remove font color in disabled input

Tags: css, disabled-input

http://jsfiddle.net/NUDDv/

HTML:

```
<div class="red">
    <input type="text" value="text" disabled="disabled">
    <select disabled>
        <option>aaa</option>
        <option>aaa</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="text" value="text" disabled="disabled">
    <select disabled>
        <option>aaa</option>
        <option>aaa</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.red input[type=text],
div.red select{
    color: red;
}
div.red input[type=text][disabled],
div.red select[disabled]{
    color: none;
}
```

What I can write to css disabled input for remove red color? I cant' set color, because disabled input don't look good. I would like set this in only CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep things simple. Use the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/CSS/%3anot) pseudo-class.

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NUDDv/4/).

```css
div.red input[type=text]:not([disabled]),
div.red select:not([disabled]){
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: This is very simple. Why I don't think :)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing called `color:none;`

```
div.red input[type=text][disabled],
div.red select[disabled]{
    color: black;
}
```

To bring back the default color use:

```
color:GrayText;
```

### CSS System Color Keywords - [link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/colorcharts/l/blsystemcolors.htm)

> CSS system color keywords are a way of using CSS to style your
>   documents so that they integrate into the environment that your
>   customers are using. Rather than specifying a color exactly, you tell
>   the user-agent to use the colors defined on the system.

Comment: This don't look good... [image](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/1050/52834354.png)

Answer (score 1):

`color: none` is not a valid color. Use a hex, rgb or any css valid color. If you want the text to be invisible, use `color: transparent;`.

In order to let the color fall back to it's original color for an element or a state like disabled, you can use `color: initial;`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/initial_value).

Comment: Then text be invisible, I would like this in default disable color.

Comment: Then use color: initial; . That makes the color fall back to the browsers default color.

Comment: @FabianLauer Setting `color: initial` is [not supported in IE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/initial).

Comment: @RubenInfante: Thx for the hint. Seems like IE blows it again (and Opera too).

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe it is possible, cross-browser, to only use CSS to reset the text color to its [initial state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/initial) once it has been specified in CSS. You would have to remove the `red` class when disabling the inputs.

Otherwise, you can force a specific `color` and `background-color` in the disabled state for some level of parity across browsers.

```
input[type=text][disabled],
select[disabled] {
    color: #545454 !important;
    background-color: #EBEBE4 !important;
}
```

Note, however, that there are a variety of other default styles related to form elements. You cannot expect things to look exactly the same everywhere.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vYyyJ/1/)

Comment: Is problem with background in web browser... In Firefox XP background is gray, in Windows 7 is white...

Comment: @Peter Do you want the background to always be gray when disabled?

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle third javascript line:

```
$('input[type=text], select').attr('disabled', 'disabled').css('color', 'grey');
```

Comment: `.css('color', '');` work form me and now I would like do it on noly CSS without JS.

Comment: JS is the cross-browser solution, i think with only CSS u will cut out  some browsers from your site, but if u still want to use only CSS why not use the @Ali Bassam solution?